# How do I assigning variable across numeric types eg numbers to integers ?

Tags: apex, assignment-rules

I have a small problem and the scenario is

I have two inputted number (3,0) fields which I use to calculate an average by dividing one by the other. I want to use the result to increment a date field. So Apex wont let me assign the value of the calculation directly to an integer nor will it let me use the calculation itself even if i round it to 0 decimal places.

Any ideas welcome ?

Answer (score 1):

I once did something like that(In my case I converted double):

```
Integer i = (integer)math.roundToLong(yourValue)
```

thy this please

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
Integer a= Integer.valueOf((decimalValue+decimalvalue)/2);
Date dt = system.today().adddays(a));
```